# How to get Attributes from HTML DOM in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have an HTML DOM save in JavaScript Variable How I can get its attributes.
Exp:

```
<script>
//element_html is ajax response
var element_html = '<h1 style="" class="app-control " data-order="10" data-id="48" id="heading_2_48">Heading</h1>'; 

var id = "heading_2_48";
var data-order="10"

</script>
```

How I can get these **id** and **data-order**

Comment: wrap it in a jquery object

Comment: you can access only when you append to some element. or wrap in jquery object

Answer (score 5):

Try **jQuery** solution:

```
$(element_html).attr("id");
$(element_html).attr("data-order");
```

Next one is even little better for performance, because its creating only one jQuery object:

```
var jWrapper = $(element_html);
var element_html_id = jWrapper.attr("id");
var element_html_data_order = jWrapper.attr("data-order");
```

Or you can try **Vanilla JavaScript** solution:

```
var d=document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = (element_html);
var attrs = d.firstChild.attributes;
var element_html_id  = attrs["id"];
var element_html_data_order = attrs["data-order"];
```

(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6fVdr/1/ )

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your element into Jquery Object.

```
var val = $(element_html).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var element_html = '<h1 style="" class="app-control " data-order="10" data-id="48" id="heading_2_48">Heading</h1>';

console.log($(element_html).filter('h1').attr('id'));
console.log($(element_html).filter('h1').attr('data-order'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tsrrR/

Works ;)

Comment: @roasted ... yes i edited it and posted a fiddle for it - based on your comment - so it works

Answer (score 3):

```
$(element_html).find('h1').prop('id');
$(element_html).find('h1').prop('data-order');
```

Updated below:

In above code `find` will not work,its my mistake to understand that.

```
$(element_html).prop('id');
$(element_html).prop('data-order');
```

Thanks to "Roasted" for intimating me.

Comment: @roasted:may I know reason ?

Comment: Because .find() is looking for descendants, h1 here is not descendant of wrapped object: http://jsfiddle.net/nLL5h/  To use .find() you would need something like that: `$('<div/>').html(element_html).find('h1').prop('id')`

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
$(element_html).find('h1').attr('id');
$(element_html).find('h1').data('order');
```

You can also filter with class name `app-control` instead of `h1`.You can also use `filter` instead of `find`

```
$(element_html).filter('h1').attr('id');
$(element_html).filter('h1').data('order');
```

Comment: Thanks Boss I got another great idea from your answer .data('order');

Comment: Thnks for the suggestion @roasted I have edited my ans...and I think find will also will work